# Why does my method overwrite positions in my array

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, logic, account

So I have this method here

```
    while(oMenu == 1 || oMenu == 2){
            oMeny = Kbd.readInt("\nClick 1 to make an account\nClick 2 to login\nClick 3 to exit the program");
            if(oMeny == 1){
                for(int i = 0; Account[i] != null; i++){
                    if(Account[i] == null){
                        pos = i;
                    }
                }

                Account[pos] = new Account();


            }

            if(oMeny == 2){
                String s = Kbd.readString("Input your accountnumber: ");
                for(int i = 0; Account[i] != null; i++){
                    if(Account[i] != null && s.equals(Account[i].getAccountNumber())){
                        System.out.println("Welcome!");
                         // Here is rest of my code , the "inner" menu that works menyMetod(iMeny,mMeny);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("There are no accounts with that given accountnumber!");  
                    }
                }                
            }

        }
    }
```

I want to understand why if I access the oMeny == 1 and make 2 accounts Why I can't seem to access the first one I make but rather the latest one? It seems that somehow my array "overwrites" the first empty position. Basically I want to find the first empty position in my array, so in the first case it's always index 0 and then the next time I make an account again, it should be Index 1 logically.

EDIT : Heres my code for the Account class

```
public class Account{

private int money, transactions;
private String AccountNumber;

public Account(){
    money = Kbd.readInt("\nHow much money do you want to put in?");
    AccountNumber = Kbd.readString("\nWhat account number do you want?");
}
```

Comment: just a heads up: Your first if-statement references a variable called 'oMenu' did you mean for it to be 'oMeny'?

Comment: Yeah should be, I translated the variable names to English so probably missed that part.

Comment: When creating a `new Account()`, `accountNumber` is not set so when searching for it there is never a match.  Also, arrrays are not dynamically sizable - can you use a List?  Or probably even better to use a Map where the key is accountNumber.

Comment: Oh I should probably mention that, In the Account class I have set so you input Account number heres the code for the account class EDIT: I'll put the code in the new edit on the post

Comment: We haven't used any other data structure then arrays in my Java class at the moment. So I know that I could use maps or lists but It's not preferred to use them

Comment: The `for` loop in menu 2 iterates over all non-null Accounts - `break` when the match is found to avoid continuing to the loop.  Also, try to restructure the code so UI logic (getting user input_ is separate from the business (Account) model.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean, separate from the Account model?

Comment: He means that the Account class shall only store data. The user input should be done somewhere else outside this class. What you did there is technically not wrong but considered bad practice. Programs tend to become quickly un-readable if you do not clearly separate input, processing, storage and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
for (int i = 0; accounts[i] != null; i++) {
     if (accounts[i] == null)
```

The for loop repeats as long i points to a non-null entry. Therefore the if-condition is never true.

This becomes quickly obvious when you run the program line by line in a debugger.

Next time please provide a complete code example that can be compiled. Your code is full of error, It took me a lot of time to fix it before I was able to execute it.

Corrected code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Account[] accounts = new Account[100];

    static class Account
    {
        //public int money;
        public String accountNumber;

        public Account()
        {
            //System.out.println("\nHow much money do you want to put in?");
            //money = Kbd.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\nWhat account number do you want?");
            accountNumber = kbd.next();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int oMenu = 1;
        int pos = 0;
        while (oMenu == 1 || oMenu == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("\nClick 1 to make an account\nClick 2 to login\nClick 3 to exit the program");
            oMenu = kbd.nextInt();
            if (oMenu == 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i<accounts.length; i++)
                {
                    if (accounts[i] == null)
                    {
                        accounts[i] = new Account();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (oMenu == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Input your accountnumber: ");
                String s = kbd.next();
                Account found=null;
                for (int i = 0; i<accounts.length; i++)
                {
                    if (accounts[i] != null && s.equals(accounts[i].accountNumber))
                    {
                        found=accounts[i];
                    }
                }
                if (found!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Welcome! nr. "+found.accountNumber);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("There are no accounts with that given accountnumber!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I also fixed the second for-loop.

Comment: Thank you! I now realize the bug. However terribly sorry that I didn't provide all code, Will try to do My best next time. However my Java teacher wrote that for loop so i didn't expect that to be wrong. Once again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You did not show the declaration or initialization of pos, so I think it is not working how you expect because you do not go into the for loop where Account[i] is null to set pos.  Try this

```
 if(oMenu == 1){
    int pos = 0;
    while (Account[pos] != null && pos < Account.length)
        pos++;
    if (pos < Account.length)
        Account[pos] = new Account();
    else{
         //expand array and add account or throw error
    }
 }
```